# Assign set in probability generating functional

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

say i have an integral
$A = \lambda c_d \displaystyle\int_0^\sim (1-exp(-shr^{-\alpha}))dr^{d-1}\mathrm {d}r$

$A = \lambda c_d \displaystyle\int_0^\sim (1-exp(-shr^{-1/\delta}))\mathrm {d}r$ (subs. r $\leftarrow$ $r^d$ )

$A = \lambda c_d \displaystyle\int_0^\sim (1-exp(-sh/x))\delta x^{\delta -1}\mathrm {d}x$ (subs. x $\leftarrow$ $r^{1/\delta}$),

where $\delta \triangleq d/\alpha $

the left arrow is assign symbol i pressume, but how can we get that result by assigning $r^d$ to r on the first line?

I've try

$exp(-shr^{-\alpha})dr^ddr^{-1}\mathrm{d}r$ (subs. r $\leftarrow$ $r^d$)

$exp(-shr^{-\alpha})dr^ddr^{-d}\mathrm{d}r$

$exp(-shr^{-\alpha})\mathrm{d}r$

which is of course totally far-fetched

Can anyone please guide me with the step-by-step solution to get the result from the first line to the third line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since notations are confusing, I used different notations: $d\rightarrow b$, $\alpha\rightarrow a$. 
$$I=[1-e^{-shr^{-a}}]br^{b-1}dr$$
when $r^b=p\rightarrow br^{b-1}dr=dp$ and $r=p^{\frac{1}{b}}$, by substituting these, we get
$$I=[1-e^{-shp^{-\frac{a}{b}}}]dp$$
Now use $\delta=\frac{b}{a}$ which gives
$$I=[1-e^{-shp^{-\frac{1}{\delta}}}]dp$$
Now use $p^{\frac{1}{\delta}}=x\rightarrow p^{-\frac{1}{\delta}}=\frac{1}{x}$ and $p=x^\delta\rightarrow dp=\delta x^{\delta-1}dx$, sustituting these, you get
$$I=[1-e^{-\frac{sh}{x}}]\delta x^{\delta-1}dx$$ which gives the third step.

Comment: thank you so much!!
i didn't realize it until now that we can view $rd^{r-1}$ is the derivative of $r^d$ , stupid me
thanks once again

Comment: you are welcome !!! :)